# Sacar numero de semanas que tiene un mes

Tags: php

Buenas pues como indico en la pregunta no caigo como sacar el numero de semanas que tiene un mes para el tema de averiguar las nóminas, el caso es que necesito sacar el numero de semanas que tiene un mes, he hecho una chapuza asi:

```
    $fecha=date("d-m-Y",strtotime('01-'.$mes.'-'.$anio));
    $numerosemanamin=date("W",strtotime($fecha));
    $diamax=date("t",strtotime($fecha));
    $fecha2=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($diamax."-".$mes."-".$anio));
    $numerosemanamax=date("W",strtotime($fecha2));
    $numerosemanames=intval($numerosemanamax)-intval($numerosemanamin);
```

Pero `$numerosemanames` tiene un valor de 4 que en este caso necesito que sea 5 ya que julio de este año tiene 5 semanas, 4 completas y luego del lunes 29 al miercoles dia 31 tiene otra semana de 3 dias, alguien me ayuda? Gracias

Comment: Me temo que tu problema no va por los datos que obtienes si no como operas con ellos.  Con `$numerosemanames=intval($numerosemanamax)-intval($numerosemanamin);` estas ignorando la ultima semana porque estas preguntando cuantas semanas hay entre medias. Usa `$numerosemanames=intval($numerosemanamax)-intval($numerosemanamin) +1;`

Comment: vale vale gracias @JDev y hay alguna forma de hacerlo mejor que de esta manera tan cutre que se me a ocurrido en el WC xDD

Comment: Ahora mismo no se me ocurre, Quizas exista alguna librería que lo implemente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un modo sencillo en php es restar la diferencia entre el número de semana del año del último día del mes y del primero, esa diferencia +1 (ya que ambas semanas pertenecen al mes) será el número de semanas del mes.

```
echo (date("W", strtotime("2019-07-31"))-date("W", strtotime("2019-07-01")) + 1);
echo " - ";
echo (date("W", strtotime("2019-09-30"))-date("W", strtotime("2019-09-01")) + 1);

//resultado: 5 - 6
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un modo de implementarlo es crear una función a la cual se pasa como parámetros el mes y el año del que se quiere calcular el número de semanas. Por ejemplo:

```
function nWeeks($month, $year) {
    $dayend = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
    if ($month<10) { $add = "-0"; } else {
    $add = "-"; }
    $date1 = $year.$add.$month."-01";
    $date2 = $year.$add.$month."-".$dayend;
    $weeks = date("W", strtotime($date2))-date("W", strtotime($date1)) + 1;
    return $weeks;
}
echo nWeeks(7, 2019); //5
echo nWeeks(9, 2019); //6
```

Comment: Tambien funciona, @Carmen voy a intentar de todos modos averiguar otra manera mas elegante

Comment: que malagradecido con eso de "otra manera mas elegante"